# How could we get min of two recursive calls, one which adds, another which subtracts?

Tags: javascript, recursion

We are doing this programming exercise: a [Office Space #2 - Closest Three from Twos](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5d51bc276f601f001563641d). The statement is:

> You like listening to music at the office.
>
> You frequently have to change the volume in your headphones thanks to
>   your talkative coworkers, and you find yourself using the + and - on
>   your keyboard to do so. The keys increase and decrease the volume by 2
>   with each keystroke. There's just one problem - you prefer numbers
>   that are divisible by 3.
>
> Sometimes your coworkers are loud, and other times they're at lunch or
>   late to work - Adjust the volume accordingly!
>
> Write a function that takes in current volume and outputs how many
>   times you will have to press the - or + key on your keyboard to make
>   the volume a number that is divisible by three.
>
> The music can't go lower than 0 volume on this plane of existance.
>
> ex: volume = 8 : output = 1 (one stroke of the - key would take you to
>   6, which is divisible by 3, rather than the two strokes of the + key
>   to get to 12)

We have written the following code:

```
function musicalOCD(volume) {
  console.log("\n\nvolume: "+volume);
  if(volume%3==0) return 0;
  return Math.min(1+musicalOCD(volume+2),1+musicalOCD(volume-2));
}
```

However it only passes the base case test, when volume is divisible by 13.

If we pass in other volume, it outputs:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Socket.Readable.removeListener (_stream_readable.js:852:47)
    at write (console.js:172:12)
    at Console.log (console.js:200:3)
    at musicalOCD (test.js:5:11)
    at musicalOCD (test.js:7:21)
```

Being the trace:

```
volume: 2


volume: 4


volume: 6


volume: 2


volume: 4


volume: 6
```

So we could write the code to just do recursive calls adding values to volume:

```
function musicalOCD(volume) {
  console.log("\n\nvolume: "+volume);
  if(volume%3==0) return 0;
  return 1+musicalOCD(volume+2);
}
```

However in the following tests:

```
describe("Fixed tests", function() {
  const testing = (volume, exp) => it(`Testing for ${volume}`, () => assert.strictEqual(musicalOCD(volume), exp));
  testing(4, 1);
  testing(12, 0);
  testing(20, 1);
  testing(22, 1);
  testing(68, 1);
});
```

Testing for 20 and 68 would output 2 instead of 1...

And if we do the reverse:

```
function musicalOCD(volume) {
  console.log("\n\nvolume: "+volume);
  if(volume%3==0) return 0;
  return 1+musicalOCD(volume-2);
}
```

Then testing for 22 and 4 would output 2 instead of 1...

How could we combine both recursive calls in a general answer?

We have read:

- https://javascript.info/recursion
- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/min

Comment: If this is simple recursion practice, then ignore this comment.  Note that every integer is either a multiple of three, one less than a multiple of three, or one more than a multiple of three.  After double-checking that the numbers just above zero work (`(1 + 2) = 3 ≅ 0 (mod 3)` and `(2 - 2) = 0 ≅ 0 (mod 3)`), we can know that the result is 1 unless `volume` is a multiple of three.  So we can easily do this without recursion as `const musicalOCD = (volume) => volume % 3 == 0 ? 0 : 1`.  Or even `volume => Math.abs (volume % 3)`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const testing = (volume, exp) => {
  console.assert(musicalOCD(volume) === exp, 'Testing for ${volume} - failure');
};

testing(4, 1);
testing(12, 0);
testing(20, 1);
testing(22, 1);
testing(68, 1);
console.log('Run tests - done');

function musicalOCD(volume) {
  return Math.min( // <------- will return min value of two tests 
    _musicalOCD(volume, +2),
    _musicalOCD(volume, -2)
  );
}

function _musicalOCD(volume, mod) {
  if (volume < 0) return 0;
  if (volume >= 100) return 0;
  //console.log("\n\nvolume: " + volume);
  if (volume % 3 == 0) return 0;

  return 1 + _musicalOCD(volume + mod, mod);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an approach where you fork the recursive call by testing decrementing forst and then incrementing.

```js
function musicalOCD(volume) {
    if (volume % 3 === 0) return 0;
    return 1 + (musicalOCD(volume - 2) && musicalOCD(volume + 2));
}

[[4, 1], [12, 0], [20, 1], [22, 1], [68, 1]].forEach(([v, r]) => console.log(v, musicalOCD(v), r));
```

With directions for testing.

```js
function musicalOCD(volume, dir) {
    console.log(dir);
    if (volume % 3 === 0) return 0;
    return 1 + (musicalOCD(volume - 2, 'down') && musicalOCD(volume + 2, 'up'));
}

[[4, 1], [12, 0], [20, 1], [22, 1], [68, 1]].forEach(([v, r]) => console.log(v, musicalOCD(v), r));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```